# Contar itens ListView

Tags: android

Tenho um listview, que é preenchido com dados do banco, e preciso fazer uma comparação dos dados da lista com um valor X inserido pelo usuário.

```
ListView listItens;
listItens = findViewById(R.id.listItens);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, user);
listItens.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
ListView listItens;
listItens = findViewById(R.id.listItens);

EditText etDados = findViewById(R.id.etDados); //Presumindo que o usuário irá inserir os dados em uma editText chamada etDados

String dados = etDados.getText;

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, user);
listItens.setAdapter(adapter);

int count = listItens.getAdapter().getCount(); //contar itens da lista

for(int i; i <= count; i++ {
if(dados.equals(listItens.getItemAtPosition(z).toString())) {
//Inserir aqui o que irá fazer se o valor for encontrado
}
else {
//Inserir aqui o que irá fazer se o valor não for encontrado
}
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou aqui.

Comment: @NicolasSouza por nd :D